# Trace script for pytorch ML model to deploy on mobile

Tags: fast-ai

I have a tabular model built in FastAI, which is able to do predictions correctly. Now I want to deploy to a mobile device, and I am using the method:

```
torch.jit.trace(learner.model, example_input_tensor)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py in _check_input_dim(self, input)
    295 
    296     def _check_input_dim(self, input):
--> 297         if input.dim() != 2 and input.dim() != 3:
    298             raise ValueError(
    299                 "expected 2D or 3D input (got {}D input)".format(input.dim())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Here is the model:

```
TabularModel(
  (embeds): ModuleList()
  (emb_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
  (bn_cont): BatchNorm1d(3, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (layers): Sequential(
    (0): LinBnDrop(
      (0): Linear(in_features=3, out_features=200, bias=False)
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): BatchNorm1d(200, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (1): LinBnDrop(
      (0): Linear(in_features=200, out_features=100, bias=False)
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): BatchNorm1d(100, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (2): LinBnDrop(
      (0): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=1, bias=True)
    )
  )
)
```

I have tried using `.to(device)` for the model and the data. Example:

```
torch_tensor = torch.tensor(df.iloc[0].values).to("cpu")
tensor([4.0000, 3.1000, 4.0000], dtype=torch.float64)
```

and

```
torchModel.eval().to("cpu")
```

I don't think the problem is with `torch.jit.trace`. Even if I try to use the `forward` method of pytorch, I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The forward pass of the TabularModel expects two arguments: x_cat, and x_cont. Only one argument was provided, which is why None was found for the input dimension for the cont variables. So:

```
model.forward(None ,input_tensor.float())
```